# Using fmod() in C always results in zero (0)

Tags: c, fmod

I'm trying to split a 16 digits number into digits. Using `unsigned long int` and `%` doesn't work because this type of variable only supports numbers smaller than 4.294.967.295. So I adapted the code and used `fmod` instead of `%`, but now the only result I get is zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    double num, digit;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the 16-digit number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num);

    for (i = 1; num > 0; i++) {
        printf("%d - ", i);
        digit = fmod(num, 10.0);
        printf("%.2lf   ", digit);

        num /= 10.0;
        printf("%.2f\n", num);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Save time, enable  all warnings: `double num;
    scanf("%d",&num);`  Review format specifier..

Comment: BTW: For  large select values (> 2^53), this approach only good for 15 digits.

Comment: Why don't you use `unsigned long long` which can hold 19 decimal digits? Even better, enter the number as a string, then you already have its digits.

Comment: I corrected and put "%lf", but I'm still getting 0 as result.

Comment: What happens when you leave out any punctuation `.` or `,`

Comment: Nothing change. I'm still getting 0 for some reason.

Comment: There is no `printf()` here that could print "0"` ar [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639337/using-fmod-in-c-always-results-in-zero-0#comment107286506_60639337).  Post input used, true complete output seen and output expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmod` is not the right tool to handle large integers, not is the `double` type if you wish to have exacts digits. Type `unsigned long int` might indeed not be large enough for numbers as large as 10<sup>16</sup>, depending on the target architecture, especially legacy systems where the `long` type only has 32 bits even in 64-bit mode.

You should use the type `unsigned long long int`, which is guaranteed to have at least 64 value bits, more than enough for your large integers:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long long num;
    int i, digit;

    printf("Enter the 16-digit number: ");
    if (scanf("%llu", &num) == 1) {
        for (i = 1; num > 0; i++) {
            printf("%d - ", i);
            digit = num % 10;
            printf("%d   ", digit);
            num /= 10;
            printf("%llu\n", num);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```